# How do I define inverse isomorphisms between Hom-sets?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $S_q(X;R)$ denote the free $R$-module with basis the singular $q$-simplices $\{\sigma:\Delta^q\to X\}$. I am trying to prove that $S^q(X;R)\cong Hom_\mathbb{Z}(S_q(X;\mathbb{Z}),R)$.  We have that $S^q(X;R)=Hom_R(S_q(X; R),R)$. We claim that $Hom_\mathbb{Z}(S_q(X;\mathbb{Z}),R)\cong Hom_R(S_q(X; R),R)$. Let $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to R$ be defined where $\phi(1)=1_R$ and $\phi(0)=0_R$. I claim we should define $j:Hom_\mathbb{Z}(S_q(X;\mathbb{Z}),R)\to Hom_R(S_q(X; R),R)$ by $j(f)(\Sigma_{i=1}^n r_i\sigma_i))=\Sigma_{i=1}^n\phi(r_i)f(\sigma)$ and $k:Hom_R(S_q(X; R),R)\to Hom_\mathbb{Z}(S_q(X;\mathbb{Z}),R)$ by $k(g)(\sum_{i=1}^nr_i\sigma_i)=\sum_{i=1}^nr_ig(\sigma_i) $. However, these don't seem to be inverse to each other.What should I do?

Comment: I don't know what $S_q$ is supposed to be nor did I try to follow your attempted argument. However, if $S_q(X,R)=S_q(X, \mathbb{Z} ) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R$ then the isomorphism you want follows from extension of scalars being left adjoint to restriction of scalars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've clarified the notation, I'll turn my comment into an answer.

If $S_q(X;R)$ is the free $R$-module on the $q$-simplices then $S_q(X;R)= S_q(X;\mathbb{Z} ) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z} } R$, i.e. the free $R$-module functor factors as $\mathrm{Set} \to \mathbb{Z}-\mathrm{mod} \to R-\mathrm{mod}$ where the first functor is the free abelian group functor and the second is extension of scalars.

So, the isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z} }( S_q(X; \mathbb{Z}), R) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{R }( S_q(X;R), R )$ follows from the fact that if $F$ denotes the extension of scalars functor and $U$ the restriction of scalars functor then $F \dashv U$, i.e. for an abelian group $A$ and an $R$-module $B$ we have that $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z} }( A, U(B)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{R }( F(A), B )$.

In your question you have some elements denoted as $r_i$ and it's unclear to me whether these are supposed to be elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ or elements of $R$, it looks like sometimes it is one and sometimes it is the other.

The isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z} }( A, U(B))$ to $\mathrm{Hom}_{R }( F(A), B )$ sends $f$ to the map $\tilde{f}$ that is evaluated on simple tensors by $\tilde{f}(x \otimes r)=r f(x)$.